# Setting up Hyper-V Ubuntu 20.0 To Access Internet Over Host WiFi

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I am having trouble getting Hyper-V to create virtual switches… it is suffering an error when trying to create an external switch that would use my WiFi.
At start, before I’ve done anything, this is what I have:

[image]
[image]

Then I try the command `New-VMSiwtch -name HyperV_to_WiFi -NetAdapterName WiFi -AllowManagementOs $true`…
Whilst it is working, I see a virtual switch continually appear and disappear in the Network Connections window: Video of screen capture here - https://youtu.be/gZHKeoCt_xA

The final result is this, where the WiFi is bridged, but there is no bridge visible in the Network Connections and Windows can no longer access the internet.

[image]

To get out of this I reboot.
After the reboot the bridge device appears:

[image]

I now have internet. But no virtual switch. Then if I try to create it now, using the same command, the same thing with switch appearing and disappearing in the network connections list.
Then the following fail occurs and again no interwebs…

[image]

Bridge has been deleted:
[image]

Reboot and back to normal.

I’ve been googling for the best part of a day but haven’t found anything and am at a loss as to ow to debug this. Any help appreciated